# What character can replace word "let" in proofs?

Tags: notation, proof-writing

For example, suppose I have a line of a proof introducing new “variable” $x$:
$$\textrm{Let}\:\:x\in f(y)$$
I am looking for ways to express the word “let” in this context and I would like to avoid using natural language because Math is itself a universal language for expressing complex ideas.

I used to use a character like a right square bracket or similar to it. I once encountered it somewhere, but I don't know if it is a common practice. For example, I would write that line like this:
$$\sqsupset x\in f(y)$$

Now I failed to find this character anywhere, neither on the Web nor in Unicode symbol set. Instead, I discovered some similar symbols like $\buildrel \text{def}\over=$, or $:=$, or $\buildrel\triangle\over=$, or $:\Leftrightarrow$ [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols), but those are very limited and not so much useful in my case.

Comment: Personally, I find that replacing everything by symbols does not improve the readability, so I would advice against using a symbol for "let".

Comment: There is an opposite view that words are often better than symbols in aspects of proof writing. This is especially so if the symbols are not widely used and common. Of course symbols are often necessary. So one can write: "Let $x$ belong to the set $f(y)$."

Comment: I agree with Tobias and Ronnie; I don't think it would be useful to have such a symbol, and in most cases I think it would be harder to understand. A while back I answered [a similar question about the word "example"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/346959/264).

Comment: The languages of mathematics are *human* languages. Machine readability has low priority.

Comment: An alternative: Since "$:=$" means "is defined to be equal to, then perhaps "$:\in$" could mean "is defined to be an element of". I could see this kind of thing being useful, actually.

Comment: A tangential comment: never write out entire words or even multicharacter abbreviations in mathmode without any modifiers. It makes the spacing messed up and is generally aesthetically unpleasant and possibly confusing. If you insist on using them (useful with e.g. set builder notation, or with some operators), use \mathrm, \operatorname, \textrm or something in that vein.

Comment: I think that it's ugly to begin a sentence with a symbol.

Comment: It is in Unicode by the way U+2290: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Mathematical_Operators

Comment: I concurr with Sami's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453096/what-character-can-replace-word-let-in-proofs#comment974269_453096). Unless you're doing a formal proof, which most likely you aren't, sentences shouldn't start with mathematical symbols.

Comment: @GitGud But if I were doing such formal proofs?

Comment: With all due respect, the OP is looking for a standard symbol in this context (not opinions about whether this is a good practice or not). Perhaps proof theory people can help.

Comment: Several standard settings for formal proofs (in the sense of proof theory) do not have a way of formally writing "Let $x$ ...", so @LordSoth's suggestion does not quite help here. (Instead, we have rule for addition or removal of quantifiers, but this is a different issue.) Plus, the question is not really asking for answers in that setting, given the example in the last paragraph. (OT: I also strongly advice against the practice of excessive symbolism instead of words. It tends to decrease readability, and does not make the text look more "formal" or "mathematical".)

Comment: Ah ... On first reading, I didn't quite get that the intent was to have a substitute for "let" in mathematical *prose*. As with other commenters, I'm not in favor of over-symbolicating words in expository sentences (and I bristle at sentences that begin with symbols). The usefulness I see in a symbol like "$:\in$" pertains to how it can add nuance to displayed equations and such. (And if you're going to invent such a symbol, why not Zoidberg?)

Comment: @LordSoth: I agree that comments which are technically off-topic are not ideal, but this seems to be the de facto standard way of having a discussion of opinions about a post (either a question or an answer). I would prefer to have these comments than to disallow such discussion entirely. I am not familiar with the chat system, since I try to stay away from it whenever possible, but do you think it would be a preferable alternative to these comments? If so, should we open a meta thread about potentially making it a policy?

Comment: @ZevChonoles I am not against any of these discussions, but the OP is mainly looking for a symbol I guess, so it may be a good idea not to forget about it in the heat of the discussion :) Also, I think it would be interesting to find a symbol for "let" as it is so fundamental. In this context, I also disagree with this "human language let's go!" stuff, as e.g., sometimes it is easier to write $\exists x \forall y \exists z \forall w$ than its "worded" version. Who knows, maybe nested "let"s may be useful in some areas of math.

Comment: @WillJagy Why, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: @LordSoth Some people use a symbol for “therefore” or "it follows”, but those are blackboard abbreviations, rather than good symbols for laying out a comprehensible proof. Formal mathematics is one thing, making oneself understandable is another (which doesn't mean that formal proofs are not understandable, of course).

Comment: @eush77 If you were doing formal proofs, you wouldn't need such a symbol. The act of 'letting $x$ be in a certain set' is denoted by taking a constant $a$ and saying it has a property that defines the set. This is what Andres was mentioning in his [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453096/what-character-can-replace-word-let-in-proofs?noredirect=1#comment974312_453096) when he said 'addition or removal of universal quantifiers'. Check pages 352-357 (pdf numbering) from this [pdf](http://ssdi.di.fct.unl.pt/~pb/cadeiras/lc/0102/lpl%20textbook.pdf) for examples.

Comment: The other thing to add is that, as the comments make clear, *there is no standard symbol for "Let"*. If somebody unearths a symbol in some obscure or out of fashion text, and you use it, almost nobody will understand what you are saying anyway, and you will achieve the opposite effect from the "universality" you are aiming for. (This actually happened recently on MO, a user posted a few questions mostly written in symbols. Rather than addressing the question, the comments were about the meaning of the symbols. Eventually, the symbols were replaced with words, and a nice answered soon followed)

Comment: Ironically, I used the same symbol for "Let". There's no standard symbol but you can use one for shorthand purposes in your own notes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would like to avoid using natural language because Math is itself a universal language for expressing complex ideas.

Honestly, I think this is a bad (by which I mean *non-mathematical*) reason to do anything. You will have great difficulty introducing any symbol into any widespread use, and consequently you will not be able to use such a symbol in any piece of work you wish to be taken seriously (because nobody will be able to read it!). I also don't recommend you teach people bad habits.

On the other hand, if these are just for personal notes, by all means invent your own symbol. I use lots of imprecise squiggly arrows, equals signs with quotation marks round them, equals signs decorated with question marks, and the like. I often use := to conjure a symbol into existence at the same time as defining it (because, unlike when programming, I don't need to declare my variables and I don't often redefine them in the same 'subroutine'), or simply =. I've seen people write an equals sign with "def" or "$\triangle$" above it too.

This is not unlike how real mathematicians work with each other. When two people collaborate, it's very convenient for there to be an implicit assumption along the lines of "every time I say X, until we solve this problem, I mean *this particular* object", or vague terminology like "nice" to describe classes of objects that you can't quite pin down. But of course, once it comes to a seminar or a paper, you start from scratch, (mostly) give everything real, sensible words, and don't force your audience to learn a page of jargon and squiggles when there's perfectly good English available for it.

Comment: This is so true. I once had a student who annoyed me to no end by insisting to write all the proofs in Mathemateze. Completely unreadable!

Answer (score 5):

If you're seeking to completely eliminate natural language from your proof, then it seems to me that this is synonymous with seeking to write a formal proof.  So, let me assume that, in natural language, the statement you're trying to prove is something of the form, "Let $x$ satisfy the property $\mathbf\Phi(x)$. Then $\mathbf\Psi(x)$.". Here $\mathbf\Phi(x)$ and $\mathbf\Psi(x)$ represent natural language statements meant to be interpreted as first-order propositions in which $x$ (and possibly other variables) occurs free. I'll use $\mathbf\Phi$ and $\mathbf\Psi$ (bold-face) to represent the natural language statements, and $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ (light-face) to represent the corresponding formal statements. So, the first-order proposition you're trying to prove is $\forall x. \Phi(x) \rightarrow \Psi(x)$. Now, in the [System LK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus), two of the rules you'll use for proving this proposition are $(\mathbf{\forall R})$, which here will take the form:

$$\genfrac{}{}{1pt}{}{\Gamma \vdash \Phi(y) \rightarrow \Psi(y),\Delta}{\Gamma \vdash \forall x.\Phi(x) \rightarrow \Psi(x), \Delta}$$

and $(\mathbf{\rightarrow\kern {-1ex} R})$, which here will take the form:

$$\genfrac{}{}{1pt}{}{\Gamma, \Phi(y) \vdash \Psi(y), \Delta}{\Gamma \vdash \Phi(y) \rightarrow \Psi(y), \Delta}$$

These two deduction steps are what take the place of saying "let".

Answer (score 4):

I've got a suggestion for you: Invent a completely new symbol which looks *exactly* like the word "Let". Then use that symbol instead of "Let". This way your desire to use a special symbol is fulfilled, while anyone seeing it will still immediately know what you mean.

Comment: While I appreciate the humor (I chuckled), I'm not sure about this being an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Symbols are language independent.

Comment: @Kasper: Actually they aren't. Some languages use a decimal point, others use a decimal comma. In the USA the common number multiplication symbol is $\times$, in Germany it's $\cdot$ (due to foreign inferences, the $\times$ is also sometimes used in general writings, but never when learning mathematics). I'm not sure whether the colon is used for division in the USA (my impression is that it isn't used), but it is the standard division sign in Germany. I guess you'll find other differences as well.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with others who advise against using an obscure symbol rather than a simple English word.

However, you asked what symbol to use; you didn't ask whether using it is a good idea.

It seems to me that ...

"Let $x \in A$. Then $x$ has the property ..."

can be replaced by

"$\forall x \in A$, $x$ has the property ..."

So, maybe the symbol $\forall$ will serve your needs (in some situations, at least). It's not as obscure as the symbol you mentioned, but I still think the word "let" is better. Your decision, though.

Comment: Depending on the context, it could also be $\exists{x}\in{A}$.

Comment: In fact, it could be neither: "Let $x\in A$ be such that ..." does not mean that there is an $x$ such that ..., and does not mean that every $x$ ...

Comment: @Andres. True. But "Let $x \in A$ be such that ..." is not the phrase I suggested replacing.

Comment: @bubba True. The comment was really aimed at the OP, lest they misunderstand your suggestion.

Comment: I really like this answer. And "Let $x \in A$ be such that $\Phi(x)$ ... is equivalent to $\forall x \in A: \Phi(x) \Rightarrow ....$.

Answer (score 0):

In college, many moons ago, I did all of my linear algebra proofs in symbols ... except *let* because I didn't know it and neither did my professor but when she saw I had a set of the basic proofs all symbolic except let  proofs  took the task on herself to find out and after consulting with other professors she came back with: ∵ (U-2235)

It is an inverted therefor, ∴ (U-2234), and is very frequently misdocumented as "because". There is no inference implied by the symbol; it is definitional and makes "bookends" of the proof. ∵ x .... ∴ *P*

∵ x ∈ f(y)

Answer (score -1):

Note that both **×** and **·** are relatively language-independent notations for multiplication.  One is "Cross Multiplication", the other is "Dot Multiplication"; both devolve to "simple linear multiplication" when being applied to degenerate (i.e. 1 by 1 (by 1 by ...)) matrices, and either will generally be recognized as such by any technical person in a locale that uses Arabic-derived mathematics.  In other words, Western countries and Near-Eastern countries, and most of their former colonies and subject-states - which pretty much covers everything but China (I don't know enough about the impact of the "modernization/westernization/digitization" of communications on their technical notations to comment on them).

Both mean entirely different things when the context is multidimensional matrices, however.  That is, in fact, **WHY** specific symbols are used.  If you just say "Matrix A times Matrix B", it is not clear whether you mean cross-multiplication or dot-multiplication - or even something else entirely.  Sure, there are conventions for ad-hoc interpretation; but for a precise and unambiguous statement, a narrowly-defined (and thus, of restricted use) symbolic language is required.

Comment: Thank you! Following this thought it's obvious that the word `let` itself is very clear and unambiguous and there's no reason to use a specific symbol, it doesn't add anything. Nice addition!